# How to create an online database for a swift game to store player scores?

Tags: iphone, database, swift, ios8

I am looking to create something along these lines.

http://www.iostutorial.org/2011/06/17/add-high-scores-to-your-ios-game/

However, i want it to be online so it stores high scores of players and displays top 10 scores.

it would be of great help if someone could point me in the right direction. Any books or articles would be great.

Comment: Why don't you use game center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game center is designed specifically for what you are trying to do. It has the added advantage that it will provide exposure for your game, potentially increasing sales.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am aware of Game centre. However, i was more interested in how it works and how one can create a simpler version of it.

Comment: That's a big question with lots of parts and many ways to proceed. It's not really suitable for SO.